# Criar variável de sessão ao fazer login - Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, login

Bom dia, estou mexendo num site feito em Laravel, no qual não fui eu que fiz. Estou precisando fazer o seguinte:

Quando o usuário fizer o login, eu quero pegar um valor especifico (coluna "idLoja" ) daquele usuário no banco de dados, e criar uma variável de sessão, para que eu possa utilizar essa variável em outras páginas.

Como posso fazer isso?

Obs: Não conheço muito do laravel. Acho que o site foi feito no Laravel 4.

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `Laravel 4`, para usar as sessões, você deverá usar a classe `Session`.

Em seguida, mostrarei o que cada método faz em relação à essa classe:

`Session::put` - Adiciona um ou mais valores na sessão. Você pode utilizar o "dot notation" para poder facilitar a criação de arrays multidimensionais dentro da sessão.

Exemplo:

```
Session::put('usuario', ['nome' => 'Wallace']);

Session::put('usuario.nome', 'Wallace');
```

`Session::get` - Obtém os dados de um índice da sessão. Você também pode usar o `DotNotation`.

```
  $usuario = Session::get('usuario');

  var_dump($usuario['nome']);

  var_dump(Session::get('usuario.nome'));
```

`Session::flush` - Remove todos os dados da sessão.

`Session::forget` - Remove valores específicos da sessão:

```
  Session::forget('usuario.nome')
```

Veja mais na página do [Laravel - Session](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session)